# Is it possible to specify output arguments at run-time dynamically

Tags: matlab, arguments

I am wondering if it is possible to specify output arguments of a function at run-time as a caller? For example, the function 'ind2sub' can return N outputs conresponding N subscripts if called with a 1 by N vector in the first input argument, like below

```
[row,col]=ind2sub([3,2],5)

[row,col,dep]=ind2sub([3,2,3],5)
```

This two call will convert the linear index 5 to a 2-d subscripts [2,2] and a 3-d subscripts [2,2,1] respectively.

What I ask is can we specify the output arguments at run-time, when we call 'ind2sub' without knowing what exactly the first parameter is? Or what do you guys usually do to handle this situation where you don't know in advance how many outputs you will get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) to accomplish this. `varargout` is a cell array (that you fill with your output arguments) and you will put `varargout` in place of traditional output arguments for your function. However many items you place in `varargout` dictates how many output arguments are provided.

```
function varargout = functionName(nOutputs)
    if nOutputs == 1
        varargout{1} = [1,2];
    else
        varargout = {1,2};
    end
end

functionName(1)
%//  1   2

[a, b] = functionName(2)
%//  a = 1
%//  b = 2
```

You can use [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) if you want to determine how many output arguments the user requested.

```
function varargout = functionName()
    if nargout == 1
        varargout = {[1, 2, 3]};
    elseif nargout == 2
        varargout = {1, [2, 3]};
    else
        varargout = {1, 2, 3};
    end
end

functionName()
%//  1   2   3

[a,b] = functionName()
%// a = 1
%// b = [2, 3]

[a,b,c] = functionName()
%// a = 1
%// b = 2
%// c = 3
```

**Update**

If you need variable output arguments on the calling side, you can use a cell array for that as well and rely on cell array expansion with `{:}` to fill in all the values.

```
nOutputs = 2;
output = cell(nOutputs, 1);
[output{:}] = functionName();
%// {1, [2, 3]}
```

Or if you don't know the number of outputs (this only works if you don't use `varargout` in the function).

```
outputs = cell(nargout('functionName'), 1);
[outputs{:}] = functionName();
```

For your specific examples with `ind2sub`, you could do something like.

```
sz = [3, 2, 3];
outputs = cell(size(sz));
[outputs{:}] = ind2sub(sz, 5);
```

Comment: Oh, I guess I mislead you. I actually mean how we can specify different outputs as a caller, not as a callee.

Comment: @Hua Updated with an example.

Comment: Oh I am not familiar this technique, I'll give it a try. Thanks for this tip!

Comment: I guess there must be no simpler way to do this than yours tip.